# How does this O(log n) iterative approach for N-th Fibonacci number work?

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci

I've just solved [a problem in Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/SANBAN) that requires finding the N-th Fibonacci number in O(log n). I used the fast doubling method mentioned [here](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms):

```
F(2N)   = F(N) * ( 2F(N+1) - F(N) )
F(2N+1) = F(N+1)^2 + F(N)^2
```

Given below are my code samples. The iterative version is given in the code samples in the link given above:

**Fast Doubling Recursion**

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define long long long
const long M = 1000000007; // modulo
map<long, long> m;

long F(long n)
 {
    if(m.count(n))return m[n];

    long a, b;
    if((n&1) == 0)
    {
        a = F(n/2)%M;
        b = F((n/2) + 1)%M;
         return m[n] = (((2*a*b) % M - (a*a)%M) + M) % M;
     }
    else
    {
        a = F((n+1)/2)%M;
        b = F((n-1)/2)%M;
        return m[n] = ((a*a) % M + (b*b)% M) % M;
    }
 }

int main()
{
    m[0] = 0;
    m[1] = m[2] = 1;
    printf("%lld", F(100000000));
}
```

**Fast Doubling Iteration**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define long long long
const long MOD = 1000000007;

long F(long n)
{
    long a = 0, b = 1, d, e, c;
    int i = 31;
    while(i >= 0)
    {
        d = (a * (((b * 2 - a) + MOD) % MOD)) % MOD;
        e = ((a * a) % MOD + (b * b) % MOD) % MOD;
        a = d;
        b = e;
        if(((n >> i) & 1) != 0)
        {
            c = (a + b) % MOD;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }
        i--;
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%lld", F(1000000000));
}
```

The solution using the former got a TLE, while the latter was an AC.

Now, my questions are:

- Is there anything other than the "recursive overhead" that makes the recursive solution slower - like the usage of std::map, perhaps?
- How exactly does the iterative method work? Though both the methods use the fast doubling formulae, the execution of the iterative version is unclear to me.

Can someone explain the execution of the iterative version to me?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciQ-Matrix.html

Comment: You're doing way too many remainder operations. To start with, since you always return a remainder from F, there is no need to perform `F(...) % M`, Also, log2(2*M*M) is less than 61, so there is no possibility of either `a*a+b*b` or `a*(2*b-a)` overflowing; consequently, you only need to do a single remainder at the end of the computation, instead of five. Since `%` is far and away the slowest part of that procedure, that should have a measurable impact.

Comment: As for your iterative solution, I have a hard time believing it works. The constant `31` seems to be taken out of thin air; I believe it should be floor(log2(n)).

Comment: @rici Since my input is going to be an int32, the maximum value that floor(log2(n)) can assume is 30. But of course, using `i = floor(log2(n))` instead of  `i = 31` saves a few iterations :)

Comment: @QuantumCookie: Sure, 31 is a reasonable maximum value. But the extra iterations *change the value* returned, so I don't believe you get the correct value.

Comment: @rici The initial values are `a = 0` and `b = 1`. So I think until the iteration reaches the LSB, neither values change (d is still 0 and c is still 1). Maybe the extra iterations don't make a difference?

Comment: @quantum: i guess you are right. But it's hardly difficult to get the correct starting point, and that would save a bunch of remainder operations.

Answer (score 1):

**For your first question:** The main problem is your usage of `std::map`. Insert and lookup, since `std::map` [implements a red-black tree](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (a type of binary search tree), is `O(log n)`.

> `std::map` is a sorted associative container that contains key-value
>   pairs with unique keys. Keys are sorted by using the comparison
>   function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have
>   logarithmic complexity. Maps are usually implemented as red-black
>   trees.

(Not to mention comparison functions with STL, from my experience, is extremely slow.)

So in effect, your recursive algorithm is calling another `log n` algorithm `log n` times, making it `O(log n * log(log n))`. (Saying that BST is `O(log m)` where `m` is the number of elements, `log n`, it becomes `O(log(log n))`.) This in of itself is not a big difference, but the computational cost of per operation is relatively large. Much of it comes down to performance optimizations (or not optimizations). Also, there are more iterations of the computation for the recursive function since it is not strictly binary the same way the iterative function is, even though both have the same complexity.

**For your second question:** I am not familiar with the maths behind the "fast doubling" algorithm so I can't give a line-by-line explanation of how the math works. As it appears, the approach of the iterative algorithm is composing the final result by only using Fibonaccis of powers of 2 instead of dividing like the recursive algorithm. It starts at the LSB, and works its way up.

Comment: N is limited to 1,000,000,000 in this problem, so log log N is no more than 5 (using base 2 logarithms). (This is not a hash table. You could try it with `std::unordered_map`, which is a hash table, and see if it makes a profound difference.)

Comment: @rici I just looked up std::unordered_map and found that it has an average time complexity of O(1). Yeah, it did result in a considerable improvement in the running time of my recursive version.

Comment: @bcdan I don't require order in my program, it's just memoization - so maybe I don't have to use std:: map. However, when order is required, is std:: map the best option?

Comment: @quantumcookie: about the *only* reason to use`std::map` rather than `std:unordered_map` is that you need to iterate over the keys in sorted or stable order. (Another vaguely possible reason is that you don't know how to hash the key.) `std::map` is slower and has more storage overhead. But when the keys are integers, you need to ask yourself whether `std::vector` might be feasible.